# Significado de "hambre de tres semanas"

Tags: modismos, expresiones

El DLE recoge en [**hambre**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K02yR30) la expresión **hambre de tres semanas**

> 1. f. U. cuando alguien, por puro melindre, muestra repugnancia a ciertos alimentos, o no quiere comer a sus horas, por estar ya satisfecho.

que no parece tener mucho sentido. ¿Cómo se explica ese extraño significado, que aparece por primera vez en el DLE de **1803**?

Recogiendo opiniones de los comentarios:
La asociación natural de "*hambre de tres semanas*" es con "*mucha hambre*", como en el refrán "A pan de quince días, **hambre de tres semanas**" y en su variante "A pan de quince días, **hambre de dos semanas**" ([fuente](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=58104&Lng=0)), pero el significado que recoge el DLE para "hambre de tres semanas" es, como señala @DavyM, totalmente diferente.

Comment: Parece que viene de *"A pan de quince días, hambre de tres semanas"*.

Comment: La frase "A pan de quince días, hambre de tres semanas" se refiere a que si una persona tiene mucha hambre (como si no hubiera comido en tres semanas), entonces un pan de quince días parece bueno, aunque normalmente se creería ese pan demasiado duro y viejo para comer, como se menciona en estas tres referencias: [1](https://refranes.celeberrima.com/refranes-de-necesidad/que-significa-a-pan-de-quince-dias/), [2](https://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/ficha.aspx?Par=58104&Lng=0), [3](http://refranenmano.blogspot.com/2015/08/a-pan-de-quince-dias-hambre-de-tres.html).

Comment: Pero aun así, eso no explica para nada el significado que se encuentra en El DLE, porque en esa frase, "hambre de tres semanas" definitivamente quiere decir "mucha hambre," teniendo nada que ver con esa idea de no querer comer ciertos alimentos o a sus horas por estar satisfecho.

Comment: @DavyM: exactamente: lo que planteo es es la aparente discrepancia entre el significado natural ("mucha hambre") y el recogido en el DLE

Answer (score 4):

Se explica fácilmente, sobre todo si has tenido una abuela que te decía esa frase (o alguna de corte similar). Cuando una abuela te pone comida en el plato, espera que te lo comas todo. Si te pones melindroso y empiezas a apartar comida, te dirá algo así como que "tú lo que necesitas es hambre de tres semanas", es decir, que si realmente tuvieras hambre no te pondrías tan melindroso.

Ahora bien, es brutal la de años que tiene el dicho. Se recoge hasta en refraneros del siglo XV:

> *A pan de quinze dias, hambre de tres semanas.*
>
> Marqués de Santillana (Íñigo López de Mendoza), "Refranes que dizen las viejas tras el fuego", a1454 (España).

La expresión es prima hermana de esta otra, también muy de abuela:

> A buen hambre no hay pan malo/duro.

Ya recogida en el *Diccionario de Autoridades* del siglo XVIII, que viene a significar lo mismo: que la necesidad grande no repara en melindres. Versión de Covarrubias: "A grande hambre no ay pan malo", el cual también recoge la frase que nos ocupa, aunque no da más explicaciones:

> A pan duro diente agudo, o hambre de tres semanas.

Comment: Los ejemplos que recoge corresponden al sentido "hambre de tres semanas" = "mucha hambre", que parece diferente de lo planteado en la pregunta inicial: "hambre de tres semanas" = "U. cuando alguien, por puro melindre, muestra repugnancia a ciertos alimentos, o no quiere comer a sus horas, por estar ya satisfecho." como señala @Davy-M en sus comentarios a la pregunta